# mod_rewrite: Image file name being mistaken as rewrite value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my `.htaccess` file I have this rewrite rule:
`RewriteRule example actual-page.php [L]`

Which simply rewrites: 
`www.mysite.com/example` to `www.mysite.com/actual-page.php`

The issue I'm having causes images with `example` in the file name (my_example.png), to not load due to the confusion with the rule.

I've fixed my problem by changing the rule to:
`RewriteRule /example /actual-page.php [L]`

I just want to know what the correct solution to this would be. I still have a lot to learn in the world of mod_rewrite, and I want to know if there's some implemented fix to this kind of issue, or if you really are just supposed to make the rule more specific.

Comment: your solution won't help against `examply_my.png` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend your rule with this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

It means that the following rule will only match if the requested url isn't a real file.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule `RewriteRule example actual-page.php [L]` means:

Find the regular expression `example` in the current url and if found, replace the URL with `actual-page.php`. And then terminate the rewrite process and ignore further rules (L-flag).

This regular expression will trigger if the string "example" occurs anywhere in the url, including "example.png", but also "another-example-from-a-different-url".

So it is a very good idea to make sure you do not search anywhere with your regular expression, but to tell it to match the entire url string, or at least a significant part. The syntactic characters to do so are "^" for "string start" and "$" for "string end". This would change your rule to `RewriteRule ^example$ actual-page.php [L]`.

On the other hand this might now not work, because the url really contains a slash, which is not allowed to match anymore. You might add it: `RewriteRule ^/example$ actual-page.php [L]`. Note that the query string is never used in this match, you cannot detect it in the RewriteRule, but would have to use a RewriteCond clause in front of it.

The generic use case for rewriting any virtual url into an existing PHP script, but not touch any existing resources like HTML files, images etc. would be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* php-script.php [L]
```

This has an inverse logic: If the first rule matches, and the requested filename is either a file, or a directory or a symbolic link, then the rewriting does not take place. This will cancel rewriting if a real ressource is requested. Otherwise the same URL is tried in the second RewriteRule, and the php-script.php is executed and can then analyze the requested URL and act upon it.

Comment: "And then terminate the rewrite process and ignore further rules" -- it doesn't mean that. It means stop the current rewrite iteration and start it from the beginning once again.

Comment: Let's have a look at the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l): "The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules." There would be only a restart all over if the result of rewriting is issuing a redirect to a new location - in a new request sent by the client.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HexHXGJ9 --- what would you expect in `$_GET` for `/zzzzzzz` request here?

Comment: It probably is. I don't have an apache with me to test right now.

Comment: it's not. There is `a => foo` in the get. Because line 4 ends with url rewritten and it starts another rewrite loop. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html There is a good schema there that explains the process of rewrite

Comment: If this is true, then it depends on whether the rewrites are in the vhost or in a .htaccess. By the way, your image does not show explicitly the handling of the L flag. I must assume that an L on a matching rule will act as if there are no further RewriteRule lines. Have you actually checked your code on a working server?

Comment: "Have you actually checked your code on a working server?". -- yep. "By the way, your image does not show explicitly the handling of the L flag" --- it doesn't indeed, but `L` never (since I started my career in 2004) interrupted the rewrite process, but the current loop.

Comment: And to be fair - the description in the documentation confuses me a lot. It's just incorrect. Or poorly worded.

Comment: If the L flag does not terminate any rewriting, your example would create an infinite loop, because either the first or the second rule will trigger, change the URL to "index.php", which on the second run will always match the first rule, which is triggering the process again, ... You'll never end up getting a parameter out of it if the L flag starts from the beginning.

Comment: If you are confused, maybe your understanding of the matter is wrong. And because your understanding contradicts every wording in the docs, the docs seems weird.

Comment: "If the L flag does not terminate any rewriting, your example would create an infinite loop" --- it works in the same way with or without `[L]`. It changes nothing there

Comment: "If you are confused, maybe your understanding of the matter is wrong." -- try to prove that :-) I've posted an example that works in a same way regardless of `[L]`

Comment: "which on the second run will always match the first rule, which is triggering the process again" --- nope, as long as url isn't rewritten on the current loop iteration, the new isn't run

Comment: We are both right - it depends on the context the rewrite rule is defined. When used in .htaccess or in a <Directory> container, after any rewriting pass the internal redirect is again fed back into the process. This does NOT happen if used e.g. in a <VHost> container. (tested with Apache 2.2) The docs are explicit in this regards, warning to take care of unwanted loops created by .htaccess rewriting.